# Create a QMenubar under QTabWidget tabs

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I'm trying to find a way to insert `QMenuBar` under `QTabWidget`. Could not find any solution, tried to get `QMenuBar` intilization from generated `.ui` file of `QMainWindow` but no luck

```
    self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self.myTab)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 700, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
    self.menuOptions = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menuOptions.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuOptions"))
    self.myTab.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
```

I need it to be like this because my app will have custom option sections for each tab view

[image: QMenuBar under QTabWidget tab]

Comment: Do you need a solution with or without an ui designer ?

Comment: @tmoreau both solutions are ok for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys on the official QT Forum helped me...

The solution is that you can add `QMenuBar` to TAB's layout (You cannot do this from QT Designer)

```
    self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar()
    self.menuOptions = QtGui.QMenu("Options", self.menuBar)
    self.actionQuit = QtGui.QAction('Quit', self)
    self.actionQuit.triggered.connect(self.close)

    self.menuOptions.addAction(self.actionQuit)
    self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuOptions.menuAction())

    #WARN! TAB widget must have a layout!
    self.ui.UDETabs.widget(0).layout().setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
```

Answer (score 1):

QMenuBar is just a widget. You can put it everywhere.

Why you get your menubar from .ui, instead of creating your own?

Also remember, that it will work only on Windows. On MacOs and Linux with DE that support global menu it will not work as you want.

Comment: The provided screenahot is from a tool that runs on linux, and yes its QT